# Reduce round-off Error with integer division

Tags: c++

I wrote an algorithm where I need to do the following:

```
double newval=(fg*(double)(0xFF-alpha)) / 256.0 + (bg*(double)alpha)/256.0;
```

alpha, fg and bg are values between 0-255. Due to performance reasons I want to implement it as an solution with integer values. So it looks like this:

```
int offset = 1;
if (alpha == 0 || alpha == 256 || fg == 0 || bg == 0)
offset = 0;
int intval = offset + (((fg*(0xFF-alpha)) + (bg*alpha))>>8);
```

I tested this with every possible combination of alpha, fg and bg and getting 8,388,607 pairs with an round-off error of 1.

I'm looking for possibilities to reduce the amount of pairs with the error of 1 and keep it as an integer operation. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: 8,338,607 is exactly 1 less than half of the possible combinations. Have you determined which combinations of values result in an error? There should be a pattern - my guess is it would be related to the parity of one of the arguments.

Comment: If you want proper rounding, add 128 before dividing by 256.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you. The Hint with 128 solved my Problem.

Comment: Post your final solution as an answer. That's allowed, and helpful for anyone coming after.

Answer (score 0):

```
int intval = 1 + ((-128+(fg*(0xFF-alpha)) + (bg*alpha))>>8);
```

Is the solution to my Problem. Thank you for the helpful comments.